# Schwartz kernel theorem for currents

Tags: differential-topology, distribution-theory

Let $Z$ and $X$ be smooth manifolds. For simplicity, let them be oriented. Denote by $\mathscr D^*(X)$ the space of currents on $X$, i.e. the topological dual to the space $\Omega_c^*(X)$ of compactly supported smooth differential forms on $X$. Is the following true:

> Assigning to $K\in \mathscr D^*(Z\times X)$ the function  $$ \mathscr K\colon \Omega_c^*(Z)\to \mathscr D^*(X) $$ given by $$ (\mathscr K\sigma)(\tau)=\mathscr K(\sigma\otimes \tau) $$ is a bijection onto
> the continuous linear maps $\Omega_c^*(Z)\to \mathscr D^*(X)$.

This is of course a version of the Schwartz kernel theorem, but one I have failed to find a reference for.

Comment: That it is injective follows from the density of $\Omega_c^*(Z)\otimes \Omega_c^*(X)$ into $\Omega_c^*(Z\times X)$. For the surjectivity, a function $\Omega_c^*(Z)\to \mathscr D^*(X)$ gives a bilinear function $\Omega_c^*(Z)\times\Omega_c^*(X)\to \Bbb{C}$

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your comment. I do not quite understand your surjectivity proof. Why is the bilinear function given by an element of $\mathscr D^*(Z\times X)$?

Comment: Need to check continuity in $\Omega_c^*(Z\times X)$ topology, to extend the domain from $\Omega_c^*(Z)\otimes\Omega_c^*(X)$ to $\Omega_c^*(Z\times X)$

Comment: And do you know a paper/book where this is developed? Treves, for example, only covers the case of distributions.